# C String Arrays strtok()

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

Hi I am very new to C and this whole pointer thing with chars is extremely confusing to me. I am having the hardest time doing something very simple.

I want to break up a string (request) with the delimiters "?=&" , and I want to store the different pieces in a array of strings but I cant seem to figure out how. I feel like its because I do not fully grasp the concept of pointers.

Heres my code

```
        char buf[1024], path[1024], request[1024], **query_string, *query_pointer;

        query_pointer = strtok(request, "?=&");
        strcpy(request, query_pointer);
        while(query_pointer != NULL) {
            strcpy(query_string, query_pointer);
            query_string++;
            query_pointer = strtok(NULL, "?=&");
        }
```

Comment: A good C pointer tutorial: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/pointers.pdf

Comment: An interesting use of not just an indeterminate pointer (`query_string`), but a *double* indeterminate pointer at that. Honestly the most helpful thing that can be said right now is get a good book, and learn *single* indirection (pointers to regular data) *before* you try and tackle double-indirection.

Answer (score 0):

a very basic starting example.

```
char **foo( char **result, char *str, const char *delim)
{
    char *p=strtok(str, delim);
    int i;
    for(i=0;  p!=NULL; p=strtok(NULL, delim)
          result[i]=p;
    result[i]=NULL;
    return result;
}

void bar(char *str)
{
   char *result[36]={NULL};  // 35 max tokens
   int i=0;
   result=foo(result, str, "?=&");
   for(i=0; result[i]!=NULL && < 35; i++)
   {
        printf("%s\n", result[i]);        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the most useful technique in learning C pointers was time spent actually drawing the memory locations on paper, and labelling all the indirections. Even today, I mentally recreate these images in my head in interpreting constructions more complex constructions than everyday usage.

Nothing you read in any book can compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
  strcpy(request, query_pointer);
```

I'm not sure if you actually want to copy the first token back into request here or if it was an accident.

The rest of your code seems fine except: you never show us how you allocated memory to your array of strings (query_string).

Remember in C, there is no such thing as an array of strings. It is actually an array of arrays of chars, since a string is just an array of chars.

So what you want to do is allocate memory by:

```
char **query_string = malloc(<max#oftokens> * sizeof(char*)); 
for (i=0; i<(max#oftokens); i++){
     query_string[i] = malloc(<maxlengthofeachtokens> * sizeof(char)); 
}
```

Also, remember to deallocate memory using the free() function when you are done. 
Look up references for malloc() and free().